# Can two piece of code be run at the same time in node.js?

Tags: node.js, async-await, nonblocking, single-threaded

As I understand the non-blocking concept this could happen. But the one threat architecture of node.js made me doubt about it.

Let's say I have two endpoints on my HTTP server:

```
app.get('/one', ()  => {
    global.counter = 'A'
    global.counter += 'A'
    global.counter += 'A'
    ...
})

app.get('/two', ()  => {
    global.counter = 'B'
    global.counter += 'B'
    global.counter += 'B'
    ...
})
```

What happen if the server receive two request almost at the same time. Can `global.counter` end up with a mix of `A` and `B`?

What about using `async/await` like `global.counter += await getB()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `global.counter` can never end up with a mix of `'A'` and `'B'` because each function callback will be run after the previous one had already finished. The requests will be processed asynchronously **but not in parallel** since only one thread is running for user code.

However, when you have asynchronous operations inside the callback function, e.g. network fetch, database access or a file read, the second user-made request might complete before the first one and thus alter the global state before the first function accesses it.

```
let state;

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms)
  })
}

async function req1() {
  state = 'A';
  await timeout(100);
  state += 'A';
  console.log(`Req 1: ${state}`);
}

async function req2() {
  state = 'B';
  await timeout(50);
  state += 'B';
  console.log(`Req 2: ${state}`);
}

req1();
req2();

// Prints:
// "Req 2: BB"
// "Req 1: BBA"
```

This is one of the reasons why it's a bad idea to rely on global state in a HTTP server's request callbacks (e.g. Express or Koa).

Comment: What about using `async/await`?

Comment: if you _want_ them to run at the same time, you should create an array of the promises you want to execute and then run Promise.all([<promises>])